# Returning exit code of piped command in a LSF command

Tags: perl, pipe, exit-code, lsf

I hope my problem is not too specific...

There are lots of questions and answers about how to return the exit code for a command that is piped into another command, but my case is a little different...

I have a generic command that I pipe the output to a syntax coloring scripts.   This command is executed via LSF's bsub.  Something like this:

`bsub <switches>  "command | colorize"`

Assume the command returns a non zero exit value.   The bsub is returning a zero exit value because the colorize command.

If I don't pipe it--

`bsub <switches>  "command"`

the exit value is the correct non-zero value from command.

Is there a way to get the non-zero value with the pipe?

For full disclosure, this bsub is actually being called via a system() call in perl.  As long as the bsub returns nonzero, the system call should return non-zero and all is good.

I looked at how to get exit codes from piped commands via $PIPESTATUS, but I don't think it works in this case because 1) I'm running from perl and not a shell, and 2) I don't know if bsub would return that.

Comment: Some shells like bash offer an option like `-o pipefail` which will cause a pipe chain to return the first non-zero return code (if any).  I'm not familiar with bsub, but hopefully it offer a similar option.  If not, you can call bash like `bsub <switches> "bash -o pipefail -c 'command | colorize'"` but it gets messy if `command` requires any character escaping.

Answer (score 2):

Following on Mr. Llama's comment that:

> Some shells like bash offer an option like `-o pipefail` which will cause a pipe chain to return the first non-zero return code (if any).

You could put your pipeline into a script like so:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -o pipefail
command | colorize
```

Then submit your job by spooling the script directly into `bsub`:

```
bsub <switches> < yourscript.sh
```

As a sidenote, you can also define `<switches>` inside your script like so:

```
#!/bin/bash
#BSUB -n 4
#BSUB -o outfile.txt
set -o pipefail
command | colorize
```

Then spool it into `bsub` this way:

```
bsub < yourscript.sh
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  In my case, I create the command on the fly, so putting it into a script would involve writing files, etc.   More trouble than what it is worth I think.  Instead, I did find a work around-- In my colorize script, I now count the # of error messages that are piped to it.  If count >0, then the colorize script return a nonzero exit code, which LSF returns to perl.   So, I think this is work.  Thanks again.